# Effects of Subject variance and scale in ICC (intraclass correlation coefficient)

Tags: intraclass-correlation

I am computing Two way fixed effects, absolute agreement, multiple measurements ICC on two different measurements. I have 3 measurements of the same subject from my instrument. The measurements are sometimes not reliable between measurements and I have a normalization procedure that helps with that. This normalization procedure, make makes the scale a little smaller and reduces the between subject variance and within class variance. The strange thing is ICC for the rough measurement is higher than ICC for the normalized measure.

How is ICC effected by scale and variance? Should I use this bit of information to say my normalization plan is bad?